# When retrieving value from arraylist stores in POJO , it returns me the last value stored

Tags: android, json, arraylist, pojo

IN my Json 2017 is the year , 11 is the month, and next is date

```
  Well this is my  json

    {
        "2017": {
            "11": {
                "8": {
                    "status": "P"
                },
                "10": {
                    "status": "A"
                },
                "24": {
                    "status": "A"
                }
            },
            "12": {
                "1": {
                    "status": "P"
                },
                "2": {
                    "status": "A"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am fetching values from Json and storing in some variables

```
  try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        Iterator iterator = object.keys();
        attendance_pojo pojo= new attendance_pojo();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String year = (String) iterator.next();


            /*Log.d("year", year);*/
            JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject(year);
            Iterator iterator2 = obj.keys();


            while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

                String month = (String) iterator2.next();


                /*Log.d("month", month);*/
                JSONObject ob = obj.getJSONObject(month);

                Iterator iterator3 = ob.keys();

                    int datecntr=0;
                while (iterator3.hasNext()) {
                    datecntr++;
                    String date = (String) iterator3.next();
                    pojo.setYear(year);
                    pojo.setMonth(month);
                    pojo.setDate(date);

                    JSONObject ob1 = ob.getJSONObject(date);
                    /*Log.d("16", date);*/
                    String status = ob1.getString("status");
                    if (status.equals("P"))
                    {
                        present++;
                    }
                    else
                        absent++;
                   /* Log.d("title", status);*/

                }
                pojo.setDatecounter(datecntr);

                Log.d("counter",""+datecntr);
                Log.d("kuqw",present+" "+absent);
                pojo.setPresent(""+present);
                pojo.setAbsent(""+absent);

                present=0;
                absent=0;
                arrayList.add(pojo);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }
```

And here i am retrieving value from pojo  so that i can set those in some textviews

```
     attendance_pojo pojo= arrayList.get(position);
            String months= pojo.getMonth();
            Log.d("months",months);
            months= checkmonth(months);
            Log.d("datess",""+pojo.getDate());
            month.setText(months+" "+pojo.getYear());
            workdays.setText(""+pojo.getDatecounter());

But i am always getting 12 when I am getting Log of datess

    12-04 15:27:25.220 2523-2523/rock.school_hub D/months: 12
    12-04 15:27:25.226 2523-2523/rock.school_hub D/months: 12
    12-04 15:27:25.229 2523-2523/rock.school_hub D/months: 12
    12-04 15:27:25.236 2523-2523/rock.school_hub D/months: 12
```

As per my json First i should get 11 then 12, but in variable months, it is always showing 12

Comment: Obviously it is because you are creating new instance of your pojo at wrong place (in fact your arrayList contains same  instance of your pojo added multiple times)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i fix it.

Comment: Create new instance of pojo in scope where you want to add it...

Comment: Yeah Thanx.. It worked for me..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 pojo.setDatecounter(datecntr);

                Log.d("counter",""+datecntr);
                Log.d("kuqw",present+" "+absent);
                pojo.setPresent(""+present);
                pojo.setAbsent(""+absent);
```

put this code inside while{ }

Comment: Hey, in which while loop should i add this

Comment: inside while (iterator3.hasNext()) { after else absent++;